# Glibc configuration flags to reuse the new installed glibc

Tags: glibc

I have a question here on how a newly built GLIBC can be used from different machine.

I changed malloc code and compiled a local version of glibc
From : /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/

```
Configure:**/eglibc-2.15/configure --prefix=/home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/ --host=i686-linux-gnu --build=i686-linux-gnu CC="gcc -m32 -g -ggdb -DMALLOC_DEBUG=1 -U__i686" CXX="g++ -m32 -g -ggdb -DMALLOC_DEBUG=1 -U __i686" CFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector"

Make and install**: make clean;make;make install
```

Since my prefix is /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/ , following directories are created under /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/

bin  etc  include  lib  libexec  sbin  share

**Now i copy library files /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/* to another repository /home/2/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib**

and pointed my gcc to use the library files from /home/2/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/* files

But i am getting the following error when compiling from

```
ld: cannot find /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/libc.so.6 inside
ld: cannot find /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/libc_nonshared.a inside
ld: cannot find /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/ld-linux.so.2 inside
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**I am compilicc on /home/2 repository , but my glibc requires /home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/libc.so.6**

Is this because of static links? How can this be overcome? how can i build a glibc which can be used between repositories without rebuilding in each and every repository? and I dont want to override the already existing glibc so i dint use prefix as /usr

Please suggest!! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this because of static links?

No. The most likely reason is that `/home/2/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/libc.so` (which is a linker script, i.e. a text file) has `/home/1/glibc/puzzlebox/lib32/lib/libc.so.6` etc. in it.

You can edit that file, but really you should *not* compile GLIBC with `--prefix=/foo` **unless** that is where you intend to install it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i changed the path to where i need to install exactly..Works fine...